# Ajax auto refresh blinks every time when loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i'm developing a web page which has a div with a class called `headlines`, it auto refreshes every 10 seconds and the problem is when whenever the data loads into the div, it blinks and i want to get rid of it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.headlines').load('headlines.php');
  }, 10000); 
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "blinks"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [Josh Beam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2714730/josh-beam) said, you need to use either the `$.get()` function to do the work! So update your code like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get('headlines.php', function (data) {
            $('.headlines').html(data);
        });
    }, 10000); 
});
```

The `$.load()` function **will** blink. So we can use any other AJAX function, probably, `$.ajax()` or `$.get()` and inside the `success` function, we can update the `.html()` of the `.headlines`.

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to get rid of the blinks if you use `.load()`. It blinks because it initializes a request, clears the `.headlines`, and loads the response from the server. This response is not instantaneous.

What you could do instead is use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), and in the `success` method, rewrite the content of `.headlines`.

#### Edit

Think of it this way... If the response were to never load, then when you use `.load()`, it would be waiting for a response. During that wait period, the `.headlines` would be indefinitely blank.

Instead, what you can do is wait for a server response outside the context of `.headlines`.

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'your-url.html',
        success: function(res) {
          $('.headlines').html(res.data);   
        }
    });
}, 10000);
```

You'll need to look at the jQuery documentation.

Comment: i don't get what you are trying to explain, can you put it in my script so i understand it better

Comment: Hey I referred your name in my answer! `:D`